# React role-based authorization

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a react app, where users have roles, I have many components shared between those users with some differences. I'm a bit confused about how should I handle the role-based authorization and I have the following question :

- should I create components for each user even if most of them are very similar to each other because I don't want to stuff the code with if-else statements and ternary operators?

Comment: You need to create a data structure you can manipulate.

Comment: @JothamArdel can you please explain more

Answer (score 1):

If I may put my two cents in, I won't go with one option only (either create new Component or use if-else). Instead, I'll use both of them based on terms and conditions. The T&C are

1. If the component not complexes, I'll use the if-else or conditional rendering
2. If the component is complexes, I'd rather create new separate component to avoid creating bugs by mix all condition in one component
3. If I go with poin 1, but later on the component goes more complexes, I'd rather create new component for the new conditions so the old one won't broken and the new component still handled

Moreover, based on my experience, I think it's better to not classified your feature based on roles. Because, if initially a feature accessible only by role A. Then, there are enhancements where that feature now also accessible with role B. Then, you need to update your code.

Instead, you could use something like "privilege" (this is just the concept/naming). This privilege works like this: each feature has its own privilege. Then, assign the privilege to any role that eligible to access the feature.

For example, button/component/feature A has privilege named Execute_A_Privilege. If initially, the Execute_A_Privilege only given to role A, then, role B wants it too, you just need to assign it in your databases, then, role B could get the feature without you need to update the code.

Comment: thank you for your useful answer @prowse, I don't have access to the database to add privileges to roles, so I guess the first approach will be more suitable for me.

Comment: @mahdibenmoumen you can create an array contain list of roles which could access the component. Then, use array includes or array.some to check if the roles allowed to access the component based on the array. That way will make ur code cleaner and you do not have to add multiple if

Comment: btw if you think my answer suits you, probably you could accept it as accepted answer. since it will benefit me with more privilege as I gain more points from my accepted answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const data = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: "John Doe",
    isAdmin: true,
    password: "apples"
  },
   {
    id: 2
    name: "Jane Doe",
    isAdmin: false,
    password: "banana"
  },
   {
    id: 1
    name: "Joe Doe",
    isAdmin: false,
    password: "mangoes"
  }
];


const SignIn = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
  
  const authenicateUser =  (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    data.map(item => {
      
      if (name === item.name && password === item.password) {
        if (item.isAdmin) {
          setAdmin(item.isAdmin);
        }
      }
    })
  }
  
  
  return (
  <>
  
  {
    !admin ?
  <form onSubmit={authenicateUser}>
      <input onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" / >
      <input onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" / >
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form> :
    <h1>Welcome, {name}</h1>
  }
    
    </>
  )

}
```

Comment: yes but I have several roles accessing the same components, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid all the ternary operators and not having to create components for each role even if they are slightly different, or that's the only possible way

Comment: I'd suggest you leverage on react-router-dom.